# Having trouble getting the Mono GUI designer to appear

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop, gtk#, monomac

This is almost too embarrassing to ask... 
I create a new Monomac project (though I get the same issue with Gtk#); Mono then drops me in the source view for Main.cs.  Now how do I get to the GUI design view?  I can't figure it out for the life of me...and can't find anything useful in the online docs.  I read that when clicking on MainWindow.cs I should see widget pads and be in the GUI designer, but it isn't working for me.  On a Mac, Mono 2.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

MonoMac projects are not based on Gtk#. You will need to install Apple's Xcode to get a GUI designer that allows you to use the OSX-based bindings that MonoMac provides.

OTOH if you create a Gtk# project it should work using MonoDevelop 2.8.2 (not to be confused with Mono 2.8.x which is quite old).

Comment: Ah!  I do have XCode but didn't realize you could use it that way.  Are there instructions somewhere on how you bind the two together?  I find the documentation very sparse and confusing....  Sorry for the dumb questions!

Comment: Xcode should launch if you double-click on any .xib file in your project. If it does not look at MonoDevelop|Preferences...|SDK Locations and ensure the "Apple SDK" has a green mark beside it. If not then specify in which directory your SDK installation was made.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  All the best, Edward